# contour plot OpenCV4Android Library

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, contour

I am using OpenCv4Android Library, and going through the sample program color-blob-detection.
In this, to draw the contours, they first filter it with the expression : 
   (area of contour>0.1*(area of largest contour)

```
 if (Imgproc.contourArea(contour) > mMinContourArea*maxArea) {
            Core.multiply(contour, new Scalar(4,4), contour);
            mContours.add(contour);
```

Then after that they used scalar multiplication for each of the filtered contour. what is its purpose? Is it to merge several small contours? didnt get the idea. plz enlighten!!
 second thing, why have they used the multiplication factor Scalar(4,4), why not other.

Code  :

```
    Imgproc.pyrDown(rgbaImage, mPyrDownMat);
    Imgproc.pyrDown(mPyrDownMat, mPyrDownMat);

    Imgproc.cvtColor(mPyrDownMat, mHsvMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV_FULL);

    Core.inRange(mHsvMat, mLowerBound, mUpperBound, mMask);
    Imgproc.dilate(mMask, mDilatedMask, new Mat());

    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();

    Imgproc.findContours(mDilatedMask, contours, mHierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    // Find max contour area
    double maxArea = 0;
    Iterator<MatOfPoint> each = contours.iterator();
    while (each.hasNext()) {
        MatOfPoint wrapper = each.next();
        double area = Imgproc.contourArea(wrapper);
        if (area > maxArea)
            maxArea = area;
    }

    // Filter contours by area and resize to fit the original image size
    mContours.clear();
    each = contours.iterator();
    while (each.hasNext()) {
        MatOfPoint contour = each.next();
        if (Imgproc.contourArea(contour) > mMinContourArea*maxArea) {
            Core.multiply(contour, new Scalar(4,4), contour);
            mContours.add(contour);

    Imgproc.drawContours(mRgba, mContours, -1, CONTOUR_COLOR);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code, you will see that they do first use this:

```
Imgproc.pyrDown(rgbaImage, pyrDownMat); //Divide length and height by 2
Imgproc.pyrDown(pyrDownMat, pyrDownMat); //Divide length and height by 2
```

In these lines the frame length and height is divided by four, this will reduce the process time needed.
To put the contour back on the original frame they have to resize length and height by 4, and thats the reason, this line is used.

```
new Scalar(4,4)
```

I hope i made it clear ;)

Answer (score 0):

For the time being I cannot fully answer the question but here is what I get.

```
Core.multiply(contour, new Scalar(4,4), contour);
```

The first parameter is the source matrix, the second is the multiplying factor and the third is the resulting matrix. If you have this in mind, that code is scaling the source contour by a factor of 4.

**Why 4?** This I do not know, but by the comment above that code - **"resize to fit the original image size"** - I guess the idea was to do that fitting but I do not see how you accomplish that by multiplying the contour by 4.

Comment: Whatt u told is already obvious from the documentation...but to get the required blob, 1) why they need to multiply wid a scalar?   2) when I change it to scalar(3,3) the contour gets small(obviously), but  gets shifted, I couldnt understand why!!

Comment: In your question you ask "Is it to merge several small contours?". I think that is not the case so that is the reason I tried to clarify that point.